# MongoDB $and and $or query not returning any results

Tags: mongodb

I am running a query on MongoDB that is supposed to take whatever is in the time frame, and then if it finds the ports on each specified machine it returns that as well. I know the data is there but for some reason it's not getting returned. I have a feeling that I am doing something to the query that I'm not intending on doing. Any help is appreciated.

Using Mongo 2.6.3

Query:

```
{
  "$and":[
            {
              "time":{"$lt":"2014-08-20T14:53:12.425Z","$gt":"2014-08-20T14:50:12.425Z"}
            }
           ,
            {
             "$or":  [
                        {
                          "uid":"h118177apss3701","content.data.port":{"$in":["22","9101"]}
                        }, 
                        { 
                          "uid":"h118177dcss3701","content.data.port":{"$in":["22"]}
                        }
                    ]
            }
          ]

}
```

Comment: Can you please share with us your mongo version?

Comment: @Lix Sure, Mongo 2.6.3

Comment: Did you try to remove some of the conditions to see if you get a large data set response? Perhaps try the query without the `$or` operator to see if your `time` conditions are in fact accurate.

Comment: @Lix I took out the `$or` and when I ran `db.perfdata.find( {"time":{"$lt":"2014-08-20T14:53:12.425Z","$gt":"2014-08-20T14:50:12.425Z"});` I got nothing. However when I ran this `db.perfdatatest.find({"time":{"$lt":"2014-08-20T14:53:12.425Z","$gt":"2014-08-20T14:50:11.278Z"},"uid":{"$in":["h118177apss3701","h118177dcss3701"]}});` it did return some documents so the timeframe should be accurate.

Comment: But you changed the times from one query to the next... That doesn't really prove that the original times are accurate.

Comment: Oops you're correct, however when I changed the time it still came up with documents

Comment: Ok - so now that you have verified the time attributes, take a look at the `$or` operator - try matching only the `uid` attribute and then only the port - process of elimination :)

Answer (score 1):

For dates, you should use ISODate, i.e.:

```
        {
          "time":{
                  "$lt":ISODate("2014-08-20T14:53:12.425Z"),
                  "$gt":ISODate("2014-08-20T14:50:12.425Z")
          }
        }
```